# Wordpress: menu item disappaers

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

We're trying to setup a new basic Wordpress site, but experience strange top menu behavior.
Whenever we click a menu item in the top menu, the button disappears until the page is loaded. For the "Contact" button it's even worse: we refer to the bottom of the page and the button remains gone until we switch to a different page.

We are using the Flat theme. 
Can anyone explain us why this happens and how to solve it?
Link: [www.crossroadblogs.be/test](http://www.crossroadblogs.be/test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class .navbar-inverse from your header element, it looks like it's been overwritten with some hacky CSS and goes wacky on :focus.

EDIT:

Just in case you don't actually know how to do this, check your theme folder /text/wp-content/themes/flat-theme and look for a header.php file or if it doesn't use one just find a file that contains the markup for your main navigation.

Look for:

```
<header id="header" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
```

Change to:

```
<header id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
```